# Page Directive Throws Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using `C#` and `webforms` and I am trying to load my project, but I keep getting a Parser error

> Could not load type 'WebProject1.Default'.

And this is my page directive in code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Title="Home Page" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebProject1.Default" %>
```

Comment: Does `Default.aspx.cs` contain a class called `WebProject.Default`?

Comment: Default.aspx.cs is the C# code behind page - and the actual webform name is Default.aspx

Comment: That's not what I asked. Please reread my previous comment.